# SharePoint Online to FTP

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, export

Is it possible to export documents or other content from SharePoint online using a workflow (or other method) to an external location?

The recipient will likely be an ftp location, and won't be an email address - the idea is to have a daily export.

Comment: You would need to use a remote event receiver most likely to do this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456315.aspx

Comment: See [this RER documentation for SPOline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx). If its only a daily export you might want to take the PowerShell approach to extract documents and dump them someplace else. It keeps the logic out of SharePoint and is easier to understand/maintain for admins.

Comment: You can create a console application and schedule it daily by converting it to a windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use power shell with CSOM for SharePoint online which is the best and efficient way to handle these kind of automation's.

overall solution will be:

writing a windows powershell script leveraging CSOM for accessing sharepoint resources and then connect to FTP/SFTP to trasfer the documents.

[powershell based CSOM references](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html)

[FTP usage in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867385/upload-files-with-ftp-using-powershell)

finally, schedule this script as a task with in the task scheduler of windows server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Microsoft Flow that run each time a file is created or modified to copy it in a FTP folder.